# udp packets dont make it back to the device

Tags: networking, udp, nat, stun

I am trying to contact a UDP server from a small java code on an Android device.
When connected to my home wi-fi internet, the server is contacted and responds to the packet
with data which then reaches the device.

However when connected to a mobile network, the same program runs, the packets DO make it 
to the server but the server reply packet is lost.
Furthermore, one would say that the mobile carrier of the phone decides to block incoming UDP traffic or something like that, but I have tested and tried to access my home server instead of the previous one and the UDP packet has made its way back!

So lets sum this up: Mobile network sends UDP packets with no problem but some of the IP's
will get their reply packets dropped. Am I missing something? Is there a common UDP port that should be used to prevent this? And how do popular UDP applications not experience such issues?

Answer (score 2):

You didn't identify what carrier or country you are from. But many mobile networks implement [carrier-grade-NAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT) (double NAT'd connections), which could be the root cause.

You didn't describe the protocol you are using. But the way a UDP protocol reliably works between client and server is for the client to NOT specify what local port to respond back on within the protocol. Rather, the UDP server responds back using the address the socket API indicated the packet was sent from. The UDP client listens on the same port and socket from whence he sent the message to the server.